# symfony2 jquery how send url parameters

Tags: jquery, symfony

Question is how to send to server-side all url-parameters page was viewed by? for example we have url

> some.com/app_dev.php/manage/corp/98089459/keyID/2054689/bill/45

and we want to get this ID(s) was used to create route, in our controller (to check data or select from db some things etc.).

First think i thought was parser but don't think is good idea.

Another was to set vars (using twig) it in header at every page

```
<script>
some = 123;
....
</script>
```

and use them to send requests (by jquery)... But i think it's bad idea too.. So guys any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.html

Method match() seems to be best solution. So we sent current url as string, in server-side call method "router->match()" and will get all data we need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FOSJsRoutingBundle** for the same. 
Please see in [git-hub](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

Comment: I don't want use external bundles :(